# SSL communication between a C# Server and an Android Client App

Tags: tls, certificates, java, .net

I'm using a C# server and a C# tcp client example I extracted from the MSDN and I have created a self signed certificate using makecert.exe. I have got this to communicate with one another and it seems to be working fine. Similarly I want to build an android tcp client that will communicate with the C# server. Do I need to create a certificates for the client or anything of that sort? If I do how do I import it in to android?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't intend to perform client authentication via SASL or the like, a certificate is needed only for the server. Just embed the public key you generated in the app and use it for certificate pinning.

If get your certificate signed by a CA in Android trust store, you can use Android TLS utilities without any extra step, since the verification will be handled automatically for you. Anyway, pinning appears to be the safest option for an app distributed through the Play store, which will likely communicate with few, selected and known hosts. In fact, it makes MITM much more difficult: having a certificate valid for your domain is no more enough, they need to get your key.

Comment: Thank you this sounds quite helpful. But I still hage a couple of questions for you. So when does the private key play its part? plus my server is in C# and i'm using makecert to create a certificate which will be in the format of .cer. How do I sign the cerficate? Are they signed by default when I create them using makecert? and how would I import this certificate file in to android? I wish there was a simple step by step guideline for this.

Comment: The private key is used by the server to sign (some of) the messages exchanged during the TLS handshake. This way the client is guaranteed that it is connecting with the legitimate host and not with a MITM. The private key never leaves the server.

If you want to have your certificate signed by a CA, you have to generate a CSR and submit it to a CA of choice, there are a few commercial ones, just pick the best for you as long as it is reputable.

Depending on how you invoked `makecert.exe`, the certificate could be self-signed and it's likely so.

Comment: You can import your certificate to android trust store by copying it to the external memory of the device, then going in Settings->Security->Trusted Certificates->User, then "Import" and selecting the file. Android will pop a "Warning, someone might be monitoring your connection", which is absolutely correct, because you now have the power to serve certificates for any domain.

Comment: Cool I will give this a go. But does this mean that I have to import the certificate file within the code itself?

Comment: Yes, you should expand a X509TrustManager to only use your certificate for validation and **never** use the trust store (i.e. global importing the certificate), unless you have a compelling reason to do so. Google "android TLS cert pinning" and you will find a few interesting resources.

Comment: Cool. do you know of any code samples for it?. Will do now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21443/discussion-between-mr-noob-and-stefano-sanfilippo).